# How to implement bi-directional connection between two arrays?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui-sortable

In my app I have an `ItemsService` which gets Items from Server and stores them as JSON objects in its `cache` variable. Items can be present in many places, e.g. in table or in graph/chart and so on.

For example, when I initialize a `table` - I need to pick only specific Items from `cache`, e.g. 1st, 3rd, 7th.

How to implement bi-directional connection between them? Basically I want `table` to contain references to specific items from `cache` so when I change an Item either in `cache` or in `table` - its state will be in sync all the time because it's **the same** Item.

Also when I delete Item from `table` - it needs to be removed from `cache`.
[image: Relationship between cache and table]

Here's example of `table` and `cache` structures:

Table:

```
table: {
    "36": { // it's a name of a row
        "72": [items], // it's a name of a column with corresponding items
        "73": [items],
        "74": [items]
    },

    "37": {
        "72": [],
        "73": [items],
        "74": [items]
    },
    "38": {
        "72": [],
        "73": [],
        "74": []
    }
}
```

ItemsService cache (simplified version):

```
ItemsService = {
  cache: [items]
};
```

Item structure:

```
{
  id: 3,
  parent_id: 1, 
  name: 'First Item', 
  siblings: [1,2,3],
  active_users: [{user_id: 1, avatar_url: 'http://...'}, ...],
  // 50 more fields :)
}
```

Also need to point out that I use `angular-ui-sortable` plugin to allow dragging of Items between columns/rows and I need to provide `ng-model` with array(*I think*). Here's how it looks right now:

```
<td ui-sortable="vm.sortableOptions"
    ng-model="vm.table[row.id][column.id]">
  <sb-item itemid={{item.id}} 
           ng-repeat="item in vm.table[row.id][column.id]">
  </sb-item>
</td>
```

Comment: You should show us both arrays' structures, since there are so many ways to do that, that it will depend on how their structures are.

Comment: I have provided structures

Comment: The  `items` structure is the most important.

Comment: Item is a complex object. Will provide its example in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless for some reason you have to use two **separate** arrays, have you considered using a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be objects. Variables that hold objects in javascript aren't really holding the object but a reference to said object. When you pass that variable into another one, the reference value gets copied so both variables point toward the same object.

```
var a = { 0: 'Property 0' };
var b = a;
b[0] = 'Property 0!'; //a[0] also the same.
delete b[0]; //a[0] nor b[0] exist anymore.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using objects (rather than JSON) would work.

Then your cache and your table both point to same item objects. If you change something in the object, it is reflected at both ends.

```
var cacheArray = [{ item: 1 }, { item: 2}];  
table[0][0] = cacheArray[0];  
console.log(table[0][0].item);  // 1 
cacheArray[0].item = 9;  
console.log(table[0][0].item);  // 9.
```

Please note that the array and the table have not changed. They still point to the same objects.